# How to Undo git add -f?

Tags: git, gitignore

I hava a folder `.idea/` in my repository, and it is on the `.gitignore` list.

For some reason, I had used `git add .idea/ -f` to force git add `.idea` folder to my repos.

I just want to do this once.

But I found when I use `git add .` in anther time, git still add `.idea`'s change to my repository. It is not my willing, How to solve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the thing is that .gitignore works for *untracked* files only. If the files inside .idea are already part of the project (because you added them on previous revisions) then git will start telling you when the files are modified even though it's inside .gitignore. What you can then do to avoid git from telling you about these files (assuming you want to keep them in the history of the project) is to force git to not care about them anymore. Than can be achieved with `git update-index --assume-unchanged`. That is a 'per repo' operation so other developers will have to do the same on their repos as well.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index

As a side note, adding metadata like IDE files into the project is not considered a good idea but it's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that Git is mainly about making *new* commits.  To make a new commit, you will, in general, run `git commit`.  This uses whatever files are in the *index* at this time.  The files that are in the index are:

- Those that were in the index when you started, and are still there because you have not changed them since then: they got there because you ran `git checkout` of some existing commit.
- Those that are in the index now, because you ran `git add file`.  That copied the file *`file`* from your work-tree to your index.  If there was a copy of *`file`* in the index before (because it was in the commit you checked out), well, now there's a *different* copy in the index.  If there *wasn't* a file named *`file`* in the index before (for whatever reason), well, now there *is*.

The index is also called the *staging area*.  When you use `git status`, Git compares the index's contents to the `HEAD` (current) commit's contents, and tell you what's *different*, saying that these are *changes staged for commit*.

Files that are in the index are called *tracked* files.

#### Remove the tracked copy of a file

You can use `git rm --cached file` to remove the *index* copy of any file without touching the *work-tree* copy of that file.  So if `.idea/somefile` is in the index *right now*, you can remove it with `git rm --cached .idea/somefile`.  You can remove all the files that are in the index that start with `.idea/` using `git rm -r --cached .idea`: this won't touch your work-tree (where you can see your files and work on them), but will remove all `.idea/*` and `.idea/**/*` files from the index.

#### Old commits won't change; this presents a new danger

No matter what you do *now*, any commit that had `.idea/somefile` in it before will continue to have `.idea/somefile` in it afterward.  That commit *cannot be changed;* the most you can do is to stop using it.  For instance, you could make a new and improved commit, that has all the same files in the same versions, *except* that it omits `.idea/somefile`.  Then, instead of the original commit (which continues to have `.idea/somefile` in it), you use the new commit (which doesn't), so that Git does not attempt to create `.idea/somefile` when you extract the new commit.

But suppose that you *do* check out the old commit.  When you do so, `.idea/somefile` will be *in* that old commit.  That file will be copied into your index (so that `.idea/somefile` is now *back in the index*) **and** to your work-tree (so that `.idea/somefile` in your work-tree has been replaced with the saved one from the commit).  If you now choose to switch from that old commit back to a newer commit that *doesn't* have `.idea/somefile`, Git will see that `.idea/somefile` is in your index *and* in your work-tree, and that these two match the file in the commit you're moving away from.  So Git will *remove* `.idea/somefile` from *both your index **and** your work-tree* and move to the new commit.

If these files are important and difficult to recover, you must become *very careful* when visiting historic commits that have the files, once you have made new commits that *don't* save these files.  You may, for instance, wish to move the work-tree's `.idea` directory ("folder") out of the way first, so that when Git extracts the old commit, it makes a new `.idea` that you can discard when you go back to the newer commits.

Note that Git doesn't actually store directories at all.  Git stores only the *files*—and not individually either, just inside one or more commits.  Whenever you check out some commit containing some file whose name is `.idea/somefile`, Git *will* extract it, *creating* `.idea/` if that's necessary to do so.  But `.idea/` itself is *not* in Git, just `.idea/somefile`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove .idea/ from git cache:

```
$ git rm -r --cached .idea
```

Make sure .idea/ is added in `.gitignore` list. Now, git supposed to ignore `.idea` directory:

```
$ git status
# .idea/ is ignored
```

Comment: Normally this is not as simple to do as just removing the files moving forward. If you decide to go back to a revision that still has the .idea directory, git will complain.... if you checkout -f to get there, you overwrite the current files with the old ones... and if you go back to where you were to continue working, the files will be gone.... in other words, to do this removal _correctly_ you should actually remove the .idea project from the project history (having to rewrite history, actually).

Answer (score 0):

Incase others come here to answer a different question: how to undo `git add -f` to like it was before, allowing future git add -f to work if you want to add it, but otherwise keeping the ignore as it is, I saw that a regular `git reset` worked great for me.